Testing for strong homomorphism in polynomial time
Let $G$ and $H$ be graphs. We say that a map $f:V(G)\rightarrow V(H)$ is a strong homomorphism if for all $u,v\in V(G)$ it holds that $(u,v)\in E(G)$ if, and only if, $(f(u),f(g))\in E(H)$.
Fix $H$ and consider the problem of deciding whether an input graph $G$ has a strong homomorphism mapping into $H$. We are asked to find a polynomial time algorithm for this (polynomial in $\left|V\left(G\right)\right|$, keeping in mind that $|V(H)|$ is constant).
The problem is easy if $|V(G)|\leq |V(H)|$. How to deal with the case $|V(G)|>|V(H)|$?

Certainly if $|V(G)| > |V(H)|$, and even possibly if not, there must be two vertices $u,v \in V(G)$ with $f(u) = f(v)$. What does this mean from the point of view of the strong homomorphism? It means that for all vertices $w\in V(G)$ (possibly the same as $u$ and $v$), we have $$uw \in E(G) \iff f(u)f(w)\in E(H) \iff f(v) f(w) \in E(H) \iff vw \in E(G).$$ In other words, $u$ and $v$ have the same set of adjacent vertices.
We can identify when $G$ has two vertices like this in cubic time even if we don't try to be clever about it. If we find that $u$ has the same set of adjacent vertices as $v$, then we can reduce the problem to checking if $G-v$ has a strong homomorphism to $H$. (Once we find one, we can extend it to $G$ by defining $f(v)$ to be $f(u)$.)
Repeat this reduction until there are no more pairs of vertices with the same set of neighbors. (In fact, this doesn't have to be done iteratively; it is more efficient to just group the vertices of $G$ by their sets of neighbors.) Let $G'$ be the graph we're left with. At this point, by reversing the observation at the start of this answer, any strong homomorphism $f\colon V(G') \to V(H)$ must be injective. Therefore if $|V(G')| > |V(H)|$, no strong homomorphism can exist (and if $|V(G')| \le |V(H)|$, brute force suffices to finish).
